# IE8 disappearing content bug even with not positioned elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I got the disappearing content bug (hasLayout) in IE8, I read about it and about the absolute positioned elements, but even with zoom:1; height:1%; still disappearing.

I got a function '.mouseup' and that is the trigger of the bug and its not just one element but all the elements below.

I hope i explain myself well. some idea of how to fix this?

Comment: i'm going to add a jsfiddle to this...

Comment: the code pretty huge so if you want to take a look i'll send you an url

Comment: http://mobile.dpr.netquarks.com/csm/fr/csm/diagnostic.php

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine in IE8 + IE7 to me, what specifically is disappearing?

Comment: when you check 'brillance' there's the violet box that appears, then click the handler and the rest dissapear...

Comment: the first one, then you move the handler on the box

Comment: man that's weird, i'll keep searching what is wrong here, thanks anyway bro!